# Set up apt-mirror with a specific kernel`s version

Tags: upgrade, kernel, versions, mirrors, apt-mirror

I create a local mirror from ubuntu focal with apt-mirror, what would be used to update between LTS mini-versions (20.04.2 -> 20.04.3) in office. I need a kernel specific versions (5.4.0-81 generic, but after server update from mirror kernel`s version is 5.4.0-90 generic).  How can i mark a kernel current version for a update?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you think you need a specific kernel version?  This is generally a very bad way to go about things. It's better if you ask about the actual problem and provide details about that problem.

Comment: i don`t think this is a XY problem, because my task is creating mirror for update servers version with a specific kernel`s version, which i can`t reach.

Comment: OK but why?  As you just found out, the kernel will be updated and replaced. Whatever reason you believe you need a specific kernel version is probably not the best way of handling things.  It will likely cause more problems down the road and it's not a long term solution.

Comment: Because programms, what created in a company, work stabily with this kernel`s version, and didn`t work untill now with a higher versions.